# Can token stream be changed at runtime?

Tags: java, sql, antlr3

I need to parse SQL Server *if statements* in **ANTLR 3**. SQL Server if statements are as:

```
IF expression BEGIN? statements END?
```

Since *BEGIN* and *END* are optional. I just need to add *BEGIN* and *END* tokens in **ANTLR** token stream at runtime if these are not specified in the token stream.

Comment: Why don't you just mark the tokens as optional in the grammar?

Comment: I made these optional but I got warnings Decision can match multiple alternatives... Actually I have a grammar which imports another grammar and somehow if statement parsing is conflicting with the rules written in imported grammar. I tried to figure out the warnings through ANTLR works but it shows loads of NoViableAlt errors without running the test cases and doesn't produce the syntax diagrams or tree.

Comment: SQL syntax is not trivial to parse, have you looked at existing grammars as in http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/list.html?

Comment: Yes, I have seen them and found them really helpful. I am working over DB2 SQL and SQL Server t-sql interpreter and grammars at antlr3 won't serve the purpose we want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by adding predicates as:

> IF expression {input.LA(1) == BEGIN}? => BEGIN statements_list END 
>   | statements_list